# SASweave and server SAS?

Tags: latex, sas, sweave

We would like to implement SASweave, but our department runs off of a server version of SAS. Has anyone implemented this setup? I would be interested to hear about your experiences, whether positive or negative. If it doesn't work with server SAS, I'd like to know beforehand so that I can spare our IT group the fun of fighting with it.